# how to inject javascript at header and body using gulp

Tags: gulp, task

I want to inject javascript library inside head tag and my customized and my own code at body using GULP.

For Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <!-- injectJS -->
         <script src="jquery.js">
         <script src="d3.js">
      <!-- injected -->
    </head>

    <body>
      <!-- injectJS -->
         <script src="index.js">
      <!-- injected -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what GULP is. GULP is just a task-runner. It doesn't directly add html to your pages. You can configure GULP with some plugins to combine javascript files to a head.js and body.js. And then you can use those 2 files instead of adding every dependency file to the DOM.

Comment: Have you looked at gulp-inject for example?

Comment: @Mark Thanks, now i went through https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [gulp-template](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-template) to do exactly this. Your index.html would then have to be adjusted. e.g.:

```
<% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= file %>" inline></script>
<% }); %>
```

In this example your gulpfile task would look something like:

```
gulp.task('index', () =>
    gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(template({scripts: ['script.js', 'another-one.js']}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    );
```

---

Another way to achieve this would be using [gulp-inject](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject). I prefer gulp-template though.